# How do I create a simple generic factory in C# with support for constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, generics, parameters, constructor, factory

I'm trying to find out how to create a generic factory in C# that supports constructor parameters.

I created some code to show what I have so far: -

```
public class Factory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _funcs = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public T Create<T>(Action<T> init) where T : class
    {
        // Lambdas
        var factory = GetFactoryMethod<T>();
        var instance = factory.Invoke();

        init(instance);

        return instance;
    }

    private Func<T> GetFactoryMethod<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if (!_funcs.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            var ctor = type.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.CreateInstance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new Type[] { }, null);

            var ctorExpression = Expression.New(ctor);
            var compiledLamda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(ctorExpression).Compile();
            _funcs[type] = compiledLamda;

            return compiledLamda;
        }

        return (Func<T>)_funcs[type];
    }
}
```

I added a little test bed in a console app. There's the classes followed by the calling code in main():-

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Person : IPerson
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private Person() { }
}

public interface ICar
{
    string Colour { get; set; }
    int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
    string PetName { get; set; }
    string Make { get; set; }
    string Model { get; set; }
    IPerson Driver { get; set; }
}

public class Car : ICar
{
    public Car()
    {

    }
    public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public IPerson Driver { get; set; }
}
```

Main():

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new Factory();

        // create cars
        ICar car1 = factory.Create<Car>(p => p.PetName = "Speedy");
        car1.Driver = factory.Create<Person>(p => p.Name = "Bob");
        ICar car2 = factory.Create<Car>(p => p.PetName = "Bumpy");
        car2.Driver = factory.Create<Person>(p => p.Name = "Jo");

        // add to list
        IList<ICar> cars = new List<ICar>();
        cars.Add(car1);
        cars.Add(car2);

        foreach (var car in cars)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Car pet name: {car.PetName} - driven by: {car.Driver.Name}\n");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

So what I'm wanting to do is have this same type of factory but to be able to pass in arguments that can be passed to the constructor via constructor parameters.

So, in calling code, if the constructor for the Car class took Make, Model and Colour as parameters, how could I implemented a generic factory to accept these? And, of course, the parameters could be of any type.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would advise not to reinvent the wheel, but if you want to understand how it can be done - you should take a look at how DI containers (such as Autofac or Ninject or Unity) are implementing constructor arguments. What you are trying to do is far from simple as well.

Comment: I think it's fundamentally wrong that you are specifying a concrete class for your `Create` methods. If you require knowing about the concrete class, what's the benefit of the factory? You should be specifying the interface, not the concrete class. Factories are supposed to decouple creation from concrete implementation details.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, I know... this is just some quick code to illustrate what I am wanting to do with the parameters.